# Create controllers test with services layer mocking which will run actual container(e.g. tomcat, maybe with changing spring context file)

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have an application with this layer

1. Resources (controllers/endpoints) written using Jersey,
2. Services, I have services interfaces and their actual implementation. In resources I'm using @Autowired Spring annotation to set the services interfaces their implementation instance/bean.

I want to write test using Spring, JUnit, Mockito, etc. which will run tomcat(or other container), then mock the services and run the test.
I already did it using stubs, but I think there should be a way without using stabs. It's running grizzly with replacing context to test context(the context excludes services implementations package and instead of it using stubs package), setting mocked services into stubs, after that I can mock services and like to usual unit tests test the endpoints.

Any idea how I can do it without using stubs (into resources directly insert mocked services)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Springs MockMvc you can invoke your HTTP endpoints and have full access to your service instances. So you can get your services injected into the JUnit test class and treat them there with your mocks as you like.
So there is no need to start a tomcat, which makes the tests much faster and debugging easier.
This approach requires that your endpoints are methods in Spring controllers  with @RequestMapping, which is something els than Jersey, that you are using now.
But I can realy recomand it, works good.

Comment: Yes, agree with you, MockMvc is not working with Jersey. My project is huge, I don't want to move to Spring MVC. Thank you for your answer.